# Access despite deny from entry in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I blocked an IP using htaccess:

```
order allow,deny
deny from dynamicip-176-212-139-222.pppoe.barnaul.ertelecom.ru
allow from all
```

But it seems the IP still gets access as my access log file still shows many entries of this IP with the code 200.

With other IPs it worked perfectly fine (there are about 700 deny-from-entries in the htaccess).

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dynamicip-176-212-139-222.pppoe.barnaul.ertelecom.ru.` does not resolve to anything:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dynamicip-176-212-139-222.pppoe.barnaul.ertelecom.ru. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
barnaul.ertelecom.ru.   3595    IN      SOA     ns6.ertelecom.ru. noc.ertelecom.ru. 2012042601 86400 1800 604800 86400
```

You can simply add the IP address instead of the domain name:

```
deny from 176.212.139.222
```